# Only page one printing

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, rdlc, localreport

I am using the LocalReport.Render technique to print a report from a Windows Form Application, as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252172.aspx

It works, but only the first page prints.  I am not using any header or footer on the report page, only a body.  No child relationships, no subreports.  Just a very simple list of data objects.

I am doing something like this to load the datasource into the report:

```
List<mysimpledataobject> MyData = new List<mysimpledataobject>();
... add 10 items to the list ...
report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Sales", MyData));
```

Only the first page renders.  I thought maybe all the pages were rendering into the list of streams and maybe only the first page is actually being sent to the printer, but when I debug and look at the list of streams all I see is one item.  The stream should have one item in the list of streams for each page.

Portion of the render code looks like this:

```
report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);

foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
    stream.Position = 0;
```

The m_streams list only has 1 item in it, so only that 1 page prints.

I have also tried passing a DataTable and an Array of the business objects as the datasource, but that does not work either.

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Some thoughts: have you tried rendering to PDF yet? And perhaps vary the printer, maybe even try something like PdfWriter?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render all pages of your report, you need to set **0** to `StartPage` setting in `DeviceInfo`.

The default value of `StartPage` and `EndPage` is **1**. That's why you always render only first page.

Example:

```
string mime, encoding, fileNameExtension;
string[] streams;
Warning[] warnings;
byte[] bytes = report.Render("IMAGE", @"<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>TIFF</OutputFormat><StartPage>0</StartPage></DeviceInfo>", out mime, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
```